# Is it possible to login with application user in jboss 7.2 using jboss-cli?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-cli

I am asking this question because there were recently some password changes to the user. I am trying to figure out the most current password which means, I have to try both. The application for this has not been deployed yet, so I need a way to validate this in Jboss itself. I am using JBOSS AS 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, jboss-cli only allows authentication for users in ManagementRealm by default, so probably the easiest way is to check the properties files.

You say you have two passwords, which means there is not much work to do:

1. Open JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties
2. Notice the instructions: username=MD5("username:ApplicationRealm:password")
3. Try to hash your user with both passwords and check which of the hashes is present in the properties file.

Best regards

Jan